# lock (objectReference) { } isn't locking critical section

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, mutex

I have a multidimensional array with mutexes, and I use them so some critical sections. At the end is sketch of my class.

Now, I tried to add and delete characters in different threads without stopping, and at the same time getting characters from another thread to test if my server will work properly, but I get an exception when I try to get a character that says something like this: "Collection was modified during foreach.."

Anyone knows why? I have read the documentation of the lock statement in MSDN and it should work, I don't know what I am doing wrong. Maybe `new object[]` can't be used as a mutex?

If `lock(objectReference)` shouldn't be used in this case, what should I use instead?

Sketch of my class:

```
partial class MapCharacter
{
    public MapCharacter()
    {
        mutexes = new object[5, 5];
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
            {
                mutexes[x, y] = new object();
            }
        }
    }

    object[,] mutexes;

    public object RequestMutex(int x, int y)
    {
        return mutexes[x, y];
    }

    public void RemoveCharacter(Character characterToRemove)
    {
        lock (RequestMutex(characterToRemove.X, characterToRemove.Y))
        {
            loggedCharacters.Remove(characterToRemove);
        }
    }

    public void AddCharacter(Character characterToAdd)
    {
        lock (RequestMutex(characterToRemove.X, characterToRemove.Y))
        {
            loggedCharacters.Add(characterToAdd);
        }
    }

    public Character[] GetCharacters(int x, int y)
    {
        lock (RequestMutex(characterToRemove.X, characterToRemove.Y))
        {
            foreach (var charact in loggedCharacters)
            {
                // exception here
            }
        }
    }

    // more methods that use the mutex when trying to remove/add/modify characters
}
```

Comment: And where is loggedCharacters coming from? Your code sample is flawed anyway. If you only want to shield loggedCharacters why don't you have ONE lockLoggedCharacters object? What is the reason for the array with objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are locking the individual characters but not `loggedCharacters`. You need to protect `loggedCharacters` with a lock or make it a concurrent collection in order to avoid that exception.

Comment: But the only place I use loggedCharacters is inside lock() statements using RequestMutex, and I just use one coordinate (x = 0, y = 0). If always use RequestMutex(0, 0) those methods shouldn't run at the same time, right?

Comment: It's also possible that something you're doing in your loop modifies `loggedCharacters`, which would cause the same exception.